# Symfony: trying to customize a collection form prototype

Tags: symfony

I have this form:

```
class BillType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder
        ->add('user')
        ->add('numberPlate')
        ->add('servicesPerformed', CollectionType::class, array(
             'label' => false,
             'entry_type' => ServicePerformedType::class,
             'allow_add' => true,
        ))
        ->add('Save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DefaultBundle\Entity\Bill'
        ));
    }
```

being `ServicePerformedType` class this:

```
class ServicePerformedType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
     $builder
         ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('label' => false))
         ->add('price', TextType::class, array('label' => false))
         ->add('quantity', TextType::class, array('label' => false));
  }

}
```

And this template to render the form:

```
{{ form(form) }}
<a href="#">Add service</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var index = 0;
    $('a').on('click', function() {

        var prototype = $('#bill_servicesPerformed').data('prototype');

        prototype = prototype.replace(/_name_/g, index.toString());

        $('#bill_servicesPerformed').html(prototype);

        index++;
    })
</script>
```

As it is said in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype), to get a custom prototype I should add the lines below at the top of my template:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _servicesPerformed_entry_widget %}
I WILL WRITE MY CUSTOM PROTOTYPE HERE
{% endblock %}
```

But when I press `Add service` I dont get the text `I WILL WRITE MY CUSTOME PROTOTYPE HERE`, but the `description`, `fields` and `quantity` related to the `ServicePerformedType` class as before..

**NOTE**: maybe there are other ways to custom a form prototype, but I'm interested on this, so will be very thankful to someone who give a solution related to this way to custom form prototypes, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I must warn you that customizing the prototype could be a bit tricky. If you change your `FormType` fields you'll need to go through the template and make the same changes as well or your form will fail to render.

What I like to do is to create a custom template for that specific field and then customize it appropriately. So, looking at your code I would do something like this:

1. Create a page template - the one you'll use to render the entire page, including the form.

   ```
   {# MyBundle/Resources/views/myPage.html.twig #}
   {% extends "::base.html.twig" %}


   {# This will tell the form_theme to apply the 
      `MyBundle:form/fields/servicePerformed.html.twig` template to your "form" #}

   {% form_theme form with [
       'MyBundle:form/fields/servicePerformed.html.twig'
   ] %}

   {% block body %}
       <div>
           {{ form_start(form) }}
               {{ form_rest(form) }}
           {{ form_end(form) }}
       </div>
   {% endblock %}
   ```
2. Now you'll need to create the template `MyBundle/Resources/views/form/fields/servicePerformed.html.twig`. It will be used to customize only the `servicePerformed` field. The template should look something like this

   ```
   {% macro service_template(fields) %}
       <tr>
           <td>I WILL WRITE MY CUSTOM PROTOTYPE HERE</td>
       </tr>
   {% endmacro %}

   {# 
      The block name must match your field name!
      You can find it by going into the debug toolbar -> Forms -> 
      click on your form field and then search for "unique_block_prefix". 
      Copy that and add "_widget" at the end.
   #}

   {% block _service_performed_widget %}
       <table data-prototype="{{ _self.service_template(form.vars.prototype)|e }}">
           {% for fields in form.children %}
               {{ _self.service_template(fields) }}
           {% endfor %}
       </table>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

I want to note that in the field template I'm passing the original prototype `_self.service_template(form.vars.prototype)`. By doing this, you can use the original fields and render them in your customized prototype. For example this code:

```
{% macro service_template(fields) %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form_widget(fields.description) }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endmacro %}
```

Will result in something like the following rendered prorotype:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="service_performed___name___description" name="service[__name__][description]"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can then manipulate it using your javascript.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah.. it took me quite a while as well. Fortunately, once you figure it out, it's kind of easy to reuse it. You just change the field name and you're ready to go. Anyway - glad I could help :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?). And prototype customization isn't in the doc (anymore?). I really wanted to do it "the clean way" using form themes, but none of the labels I've tried did work (even when c/c `unique_block_prefix` + `_widget` or `entry_widget`, etc. This is probably one of THE worst part of Symfony's _(usually great)_ documentation. And basically I really feel like using a classic form_theme should impact normal & prototype render, it doesn't make much sense to have them both separated (but maybe that's a weird technical limitation).

Comment: That's strange - what version of Symfony are you using? It works 1000% on 3.4+, 4.5+ and 5.4, because I have projects which are using the same approach (not sure for 6.0+ -- haven't tested it yet). Are you absolutely sure you cleared your cache before trying the changes you made?

Comment: FYI, the prototype docs is located [here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) and more on the field naming convention can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/form_themes.html#form-custom-prototype). You probably aren't using the write field names or haven't cleared the cache IMHO. :)

Answer (score 5):

Actually form theme blocks that start with an underscore `_` relate to a field with a specific name.

What I mean is that, if your master form `BillType` is called `my_form`, you will need to do this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block _my_form_servicesPerformed_entry_widget %}
I WILL WRITE MY CUSTOM PROTOTYPE HERE
{% endblock %}
```

The problem with this approach is that it concerns a specific iteration of `BillType`. If you use this form type elsewhere and provide it with a different name `my_form_2`, you would have to add an identical block named `_my_form_2_servicesPerformed_entry_widget`.

Comment: The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype) is very unclear about this fact, but you are right. Using only the fields name + an underscore like `_servicesPerformed` does not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use macro, have a look at below example it's working fine for me even in Symfony3. Using this example you will be able to format your collection prototype as well.

### View

```
{% macro widget_prototype(widget, remove_text) %}
{% if widget.vars.prototype %}
    {% set form = widget.vars.prototype %}
    {% set name = widget.vars.name %}
{% else %}
    {% set form = widget %}
    {% set name = widget.vars.full_name %}
{% endif %}

<div data-content="{{ name }}" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="section row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="field-label">Skill <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <label class="field select">
                {{ form_widget(form.skill) }}
                <i class="arrow double"></i>                    
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-content="{{ name }}">
        <a class="btn-remove" data-related="{{ name }}">{{ remove_text }}</a>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: This isn't the most complete/clear/generic answer, but actually the only one that worked with Symfony 4. It's a shame `form_theme` can't (at all / easily ?) be used for that. I'd recommend to read Macro's documentations first though: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html , but mainly don't forget to `import` it!

Answer (score 1):

Your template to render the form has some problems.  The first is this line:

```
prototype = prototype.replace(/_name_/g, index.toString());
```

The regex should be `__name__`.

Next, you are retrieving the prototype, but then immediately overwriting it and replacing the HTML of the prototype.  There is nothing there I can see that actually appends the new form to your existing form anywhere.  Plus since you just have a string of text, that `replace` isn't going to find any text `__name__` to replace.

You should post the full extent of your Twig/Javascript so we can actually see the `#bill_servicesPerformed` as well as everything else you are trying to do.  Before you write a custom prototype you should get the form working with the standard prototype just to make sure you don't have any bugs there first.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, this is the way I keep going it. I do not know if there are some reasons not to, so be careful.

## Form to include prototype:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="contactMehtods" data-prototype="
    {% filter escape %}
        {{ include(':organization/partials:prototype_contact_method.html.twig', { 'contact_method': contact_form.contactMethods.vars.prototype }) }}
    {% endfilter %}">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(contact_form.name, null, { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'control-label' }}) }}
        {{ form_widget(contact_form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

## Prototype template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(contact_method.name, null, { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label' }}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ form_widget(contact_method.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(contact_method.value, null, { 'label_attr': { 'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label' }}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ form_widget(contact_method.value, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But a note to consider, the javascript needs to accommodate for these changes I guess.